# How do I save and restore visible windows in Apple's Finder?

Tags: macos, finder, folders, startup

When I restart my Macbook, I want to have the folders I had previously opened to be restored to the condition they were in prior to restart. This needs to happen after a delay because there are volumes that need to be mounted first.

Comment: Before restart, AppleScript to save state of all Finder windows. After restart and disk mount, AppleScript to restore state of all Finder windows.  Might get tricky if some windows were showing network volumes.

Comment: Can you show me the Applescript to do this or point me to a good source? I don't have any network volumes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a set of scripts called "Save and Restore Finder Windows" that may do what you want:

https://marc.vos.net/downloads/scripting/